# Missing date property in Symfony API

Tags: api, symfony, date, api-platform.com

I am building an api in Symfony 5 with ApiPlatform and i'm not able to get the date property through the api for the *comments* entity subresource. I get *publishedAt* when I get **all** the comments but it doesn't work if I get the comments for one specific post.
I included publishedAt to the same normalization_context group for subresourceOperations then the others. What I did wrong ?

**Comments Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      attributes={
 *          "order"={"published_at": "DESC"}, 
 *          "pagination_client_enabled"=true, 
 *          "pagination_client_items_per_page"=true
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "put"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_EDITOR') or is_granted('ROLE_SUBSCRIBER') and object.getUser() == user"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_SUBSCRIBER')",
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                 "groups"={"get-recipes-comments"}
 *              }
 *          },
 *      },
 *      denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"post"}
 *      },
 *     subresourceOperations={
 *         "api_recipes_comments_get_subresource"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"get-recipes-comments"}
 *              }
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CommentsRepository::class)
 */
class Comments implements AuthoredEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"get-recipes-comments"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Users::class, inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"get-recipes-comments"})
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Recipes::class, inversedBy="comments")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $recipe;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"post", "get-recipes-comments"})
     */
    private $rating;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Groups({"post", "get-recipes-comments"})
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"get-recipes-comments"})
     */
    private $published_at;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->published_at = new \DateTime();
    } ...........
```

**Results in api:**

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Comments",
    "@id": "/api/recipes/520/comments",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "/api/comments/1341",
            "@type": "Comments",
            "id": 1341,
            "user": {
                "@id": "/api/users/61",
                "@type": "Users",
                "usergroup": "Super Administrator",
                "username": "superadmin"
            },
            "rating": null,
            "content": "new comment"
        }
    ],
    "hydra:totalItems": 1
}
```

Comment: please use private $publishedAt; instead of private $published_at; ?

Comment: yes i should have to but i don't think that this is what is causing my problem here. Has i said i can access publishedAt in normal cases but not when I use the subresource

Comment: sorry for not believing you it was the underscore that was causing the problem ^^ feel dumb now. thks

Comment: No problème can you mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use private $publishedAt; instead of private $published_at;